# Get "the underlying connection was closed an unexpected error occurred on a send" error when calling CompleteSale method

Tags: c#-2.0, ebay-api

I'm having a problem calling the API's method `CompleteSale` via eBay_Service .NET SDK (v967) since 2 weeks (02/10). 
When the ERP tries to sends some updated information about one order, it receives this Exception:

> the underlying connection was closed an unexpected error occurred on a send

so I haven't got a response from the API. 
There are more than one strange things:

- there are some batch in background, using the same .dll, and they
  work fine;
- after rebooting the server the first call to "CompleteSale" works fine;
- after registering again the .dll via the "regsrv" command, it worked 
  fine for one day;
- all operators that uses the ERP are connected to the server via
  remote desktop and all of they notice the problem. Instead, if i
  connect from my company's office, all works fine;
- I've tried to increase the timeout to 360 sec (from 60 sec) and nothing changed.

The ERP is developed in progress (OpenGL) <del>, so I can't fix with setting "KeepAlive" to "false", setting the certificate explicitly (Tsl1.1 | Tsl1.2) or making other interventions on .net side.</del> I was wrong, it can be done from the source code of the SDK.

Comment: Do you have details about that keepAlive setting? Where would that be set in a .NET application?

Comment: Looking at the SDK's source code it is setted to "false".

Comment: Can you please provide more details on this: 'so i can't fix with setting "KeetAlive" to "false"'

Comment: Sorry but i didn't know that ebay provides the source code of the SDK. With it, i could be able to try setting the "ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol" and try if it solve the problem. 
Anyway the ERP is not developed in .NET but uses some .NET libraries.

Comment: If you can solve this in .NET, create a small C# project, build your own library around the ebay API and use that in the ABL application.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, i'll do some tests and let you know if it solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've checked the Security Protocols on the api's servers discovering that the "SSL3" is not longer supported whereas the default value for the ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol in .NET 2.0 is SSL3. 
I've solved the problem by adding this hotfix at the "eBayXmlAPIInterfaceService" class in the SDK's source code:

```
//768  = Tsl1.1,  3070 = Tsl1.2
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072 |
(SecurityProtocolType)768;

HttpWebRequest http = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(this.Url);
http.Method = "POST";
http.ContentType = "text/xml";
http.ContentLength = data.Length;
http.KeepAlive = false;
```

Probably Microsoft as released an hotfix to correct this problem but the server wesn't updated since 2015.
Moreover i've replicated the .net code in the ABL application in a program that we use to do get/post requestes:

```
DEF VAR w-tsl10 AS System.Net.SecurityProtocolType
w-tsl10 = CAST(System.Enum:ToObject(PROGRESS.Util.TypeHelper:GetType("System.Net.SecurityProtocolType":U), 192), System.Net.SecurityProtocolType).
ystem.Net.ServicePointManager:SecurityProtocol = w-tsl10.
```

- link to the security protocol verifier: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I was working with betfair api and got this issue. After some research I found this

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```